# Triple integral of a vector field

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let V be the region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by the inequality $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 ≤ 1$, let $S$ be the surface bounding $V$ and $\vec{v}$ be the vector field $\vec{v} = r^3\vec{r}$. Calculate$\displaystyle \iiint_{V} \nabla \cdot \vec{v} \,  dx \, dy \, dz$ by any method.

I've difficulty understanding the given vector field. What's $r$ and what's $\vec{r}$?

Comment: $r = \|\vec r\|$ and $\vec r = \langle x, y, z\rangle$.

Comment: Use the [Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement)...then, because of the spherical symmetry, this integral is extremely simple.  I suggest rewriting $\vec{v} = r^3\vec{r} = r^4\hat{r}$ (where $\hat{r}$ is the unit vector in the direction of $\vec{r}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$ is the sphere of radius $1$ centered about the origin.  Given a point $\langle x, y, z \rangle$:

$$
\vec{r} = \langle x, y, z \rangle \\
|\vec{r}| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}
$$

Thus, using the [Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement):

$$
\int_V \nabla \circ\vec{v} dV = \oint_{\partial V} \vec{v}\circ \hat{n}dA
$$

But since the boundary is the surface of a sphere--and $\vec{v}$ always points out radially, $\vec{v}$ is always perpendicular to the boundary surface.  $\vec{v}\circ\hat{n} = |\vec{v}|$ for *all* points on the boundary of the sphere.

Comment: Thanks. I think I might be missing the obvious thing here but what happens to $r$ afterwards? Do we let $r = 1$ because of the radius?

Comment: @user129566 yes, $r = 1$ thus $|\vec{v}| = 1^4$ and you are left with $\int_{\partial V} dA$...so the area of the boundary of the sphere of radius $1$.