# Evaluation of $\oint_C y(y-x^2)\, dx +x (1+y)^2 \, dy$ where $C$ is the closed curve $x^2+y^2 = 4$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to evaluate

> $$\oint_C y(y-x^2)\, dx +x (1+y)^2 \, dy ,$$ where $C$ is the closed curve $x^2+y^2 = 4$.

I want to know why the solution below using Green's Theorem is wrong:

$$\displaystyle I = \iint_{R} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x(1+y^2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y} y(y-x^2)\,dx\,dy = \iint_R 1+x^2+y^2 \,dx\,dy$$

But since $x^2+y^2 = 4$ this is simply $\displaystyle 5 \iint_R \,dx \, dy$ $ ~~~~~(\Leftarrow $ I suspect this might be faulty logic$)$.

$R$ is a projection of a circle of radius $2$, and the double integral a representation of its area, thus $$I =5 \pi (2)^2 = 20 \pi.$$

But the value of the integral is $12 \pi$, not $20 \pi$, so this must be wrong somewhere. But where?

Comment: Your differentiation is not correct.. I get $\iint 1 + y^2 + x^2 - 2y\, dA$  I don't think that makes a big difference in the end as you are integrating over a disk that is symmetric about the x axis.  Next issue, when you apply Greens Theorem, you are integrating over the area of the disk and not just the boundry.

Comment: @DougM Thanks. I think my differentiation is correct. Regarding the other issue, what's confusing me is why this is invalid for triple integral, as in this answer to a previous question of mine: (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741709/triple-integral-of-a-vector-field/1741724#1741724).

Comment: Greens theorem, Stokes theorem, and the divergence theorem all use the same idea.  If you have an integral over a closed boundary, you can differentiate and ingrate over the interior.  But you could also go backwards.  In that case someone was asked to differentiate and integrate over the interior volume, and they chose to not differentiate and integrate over the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about where the error occurs: It's true that $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ on $C$, but that's *not* true everywhere on $R$. The shape of $R$ suggests that a certain change of coordinates would be effective at the point of the error, though.

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between what I've done here and what's in this answer (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741709/triple-integral-of-a-vector-field/1741724#1741724 - see the comments in particular)?

Comment: In that example, someone has used the divergence theorem (backward from how it is usually applied but correct nonetheless) to say that $\iiint div v dV = \iint_S v dS.  That is the integral of the divergence of v over the volume equals the integral of v over the surface.